# ASP.net Webpages calendar

Tags: c#, datepicker, asp.net-webpages

Has anyone got a calendar I can use with asp.net webpages? I con only find ones that work with WebForms.

I need to be able to add some delivery option per day based on what the person orders.

I can find jQuery calendars but these don't have the freedom to add options for the days I need and blank out the days we cant deliver on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any Calendar control from any javascript library as in any web application. You won´t use a calendar that is strictly compatible with ASP.NET.

I would recommend you to use Bootstrap. You can use this Datepicker control:

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Or checkout this list of calendars:

http://bootsnipp.com/tags/calendar